# "there is no way" vs. "in no way"

Tags: adverbs

> A. Such  research is not possible.
>
> B. It is impossible such research.
>
> C. There is no way to do such research.
>
> D. No way is there to do such research.
>
> E. Such  research is not facilitated.

Issues:

I am wondering if all 5 sentences could imply the same thing semantically, or whether they are almost interchangeable?

I really do appreciate your taking the time.

Comment: I'd say they all sound either wrong or awkward. I think the following version sounds much better: "Such research is not possible."

Comment: I agree with @Cookie Monster, although Versions B & C also work well if you remove the indefinite article: "There is no way to do such research." The noun _research_ is a mass noun.

Answer (score 1):

A. Such research is not possible.

Sounds fine.

B. It is impossible such research.

No.  Could be "Such research is impossible."

C. There is no way to do such research.

Ok.

D. No way is there to do such research.

Incorrect word order.  Should the word order in C.

E. Such research is not facilitated.

This is an awkward phrasing.
Facilitate means "to make easier or less difficult",  "to assist."  So, the meaning is different from possible/impossible, as in the other sentences, which are absolutes.
And then.. facilitated by who?  That should be stated.
Facilitate is an uncommon word, that probably shouldn't be used when simpler words are appropriate, like "assist".   It does depend on the context though.